# Taking Focus of an Application - OS Related Issues?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a .NET 4.0 application that simply accepts input into a TextBox, processes it and then sends it off to a database. This app is intended to work with USB barcode scanners.

I have a requirement to ensure that the input from these barcode scans is processed by this app. I have been asked to ensure that this app stays activated and focused at all times as the laptop it will reside  on has no other requirements other than to power and accept input from a USB barcode scanner.

I managed to achieve this myself by using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` that calls `this.Activate()` on a set interval, or better yet;

```
    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke((Action)this.Activate);
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
    }
```

Whilst these methods work fine on my Windows 8.1 Development machine, I can't get this same code to work on a Windows 7 OS (I've tried numerous boxes as well as VMs). For the Win7 machines I can see that this code is executed fine, but I just cannot get my app to Activate again.

Could anyone please advise as to why I'm seeing this behaviour?
Many thanks!

Comment: You could set the form to be this.topmost = true; resulting that your application always has focus. After that you can overwrite the closing handler and set e.Cancel = true so the form can't close (might wan't to add some more code here so there still is some way to close this application). disable the maximize and minimize buttons on the form settings and lock the max and min size the monitor resolution in the initialize of the form. Its a little nasty, but it will work.

Comment: @NickOtten TopMost only ensure your form will be visible. It will not ensure that input focus remains on your window, and it shouldn't. And of course, fullscreen topmost windows are to be frowned upon :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows only permits the application that owns the foreground window to bring another window into the foreground (either one of its own or belonging to another application). A background application can't bring itself into the foreground. This is a deliberate design choice (introduced circa Windows 98, as I recall) to prevent background applications from interrupting what the user is doing - particularly to ensure that keyboard input goes to the right place and doesn't accidentally fire actions that the user hadn't intended.

This constraint is documented in the `SetForegroundWindow` documentation:

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> • The process is the foreground process.
>
> • The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> • The process received the last input event.
>
> • There is no foreground process.
>
> • The process is being debugged.
>
> • The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
>
> • The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> • The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> • No menus are active.

Source: [SetForegroundWindow function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you need to be sure that input from a barcode scanner goes into a particular application, you should look into keyboard hooks, if the scanner is configured for keyboard emulation, or whether the scanner supports another API to allow direct control.

For example, the scanner may support the [National Retail Federation's UnifiedPOS standard](https://nrf.com/resources/retail-technology-standards/unifiedpos). Microsoft have provided a library, [POS for .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42081), which allows UnifiedPOS devices to be controlled from .NET.

Comment: I had considered keyboard hooks, but I'm required to use only the .NET Framework without unmanaged code. Thanks for documentation references, as well as the "POS for .NET", I will check this out.

Answer (score 2):

That's an illegal action. You're stealing control from the user, which is forbidden in the desktop ecosystem. The user should always be the one in control. Windows Vista+ started paying a lot more attention to things like this.

The proper thing the OS is supposed to do is notify the user you want his attention (e.g. flashing the window in the taskbar), it must not actually activate your window. Every time the OS allows you to steal control from the user, it's considered to be a bug, and usually must be fixed.

Maybe you want to replace the default Windows shell instead? That will allow you to simply have just one application running anyway, and when it's closed, it will restart the machine...

Comment: "Flashing the window in the taskbar", yes that's the behaviour I see in Windows 7, but not 8. Though for this purpose I'm not overly concerned for a "user" as the barcode is attached to machinery anyway, if there isn't a way then I guess there isn't a way. Thank you for clearing this up; the idea of a custom shell is brilliant however. :)

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanners typically transfer their data as if some user would have typed it by using keyboard. This lead to a *false* assumption that you need to have focus and active window all the time.

However, you could use technique from stone age called *keylogging* (usually with the word *trojan* in front). This is achieved by setting keyboard hooks in windows based system. Then your application can have all the input.

It's done by using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex). I still have windows XP software which uses hooks and it seems to work under Window 8.

The problem to determine when it's a barcode scanner and when user is typing password into login form of another application I leave at your disposal =P.